# How can you track memory across DLL boundaries

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, delete-operator

I want performant run-time memory metrics so I wrote a memory tracker based on overloading `new` & `delete`. It basically lets walk your allocations in the heap and analyze everything about them - fragmentation, size, time, number, callstack, etc. But, it has 2 fatal flaws: It can't track memory allocated in other DLLs and when ownership of objects is passed to DLLs or vice versa crashes ensue. And some smaller flaws: If a user uses `malloc` instead of `new` it's untracked; or if a user makes a class defined `new`/`delete`.

How can I eliminate these flaws? I think I must be going about this fundamentally incorrectly by overloading `new`/`delete`, is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to implement this is to use detours and a separate tool that runs in its own process. The procedure is roughly the following:

1. Create memory allocation in a remote process.
2. Place there code of a small loader that will load your dll.
3. Call `CreateRemoteThread` API that will run your loader.
4. From inside of the loaded dll establish detours (hooks, interceptors) on the alloc/dealloc functions.
5. Process the calls, track activity.

If you implement your tool this way, it will be not important from what DLL or directly from exe the memory allocation routines are called. Plus you can track activities from any process, not necessarily that you compiled yourself.

MS Windows allows checking contents of the virtual address space of the remote process. You can summarize use of virtual address space that was collected this way in a histogram, like the following:

[image]

From this picture you can see how many virtual allocation of what size are existing in your target process.

[image]

The picture above shows an overview of the virtual address space usage in 32-bit MSVC DevEnv. Blue stripe means a commited piece of emory, magenta stripe - reserved. Green is unoccupied part of the address space.

You can see that lower addresses are pretty fragmented, while the middle area - not. Blue lines at high addresses - various dlls that are loaded into the process.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out the common memory management routines that are called by `new`/`delete` and `malloc`/`free`, and intercept those. It is usually `malloc`/`free` in the end, but check to make sure.

On UNIX, I would use `LD_PRELOAD` with some library that re-implemented those routines. On Windows, you have to hack a little bit, but [this link](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/modifying-default-win32-heap-management-help-28758902.html) seems to give a good description of the process. It basically suggests that you use [Detours from Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).

Answer (score 0):

Passing ownership of objects between modules is fundamentally flawed.  It showed up with your custom allocator, but there are plenty of other cases that will fail also:

- compiler upgrades, and recompiling only some DLLs
- mixing compilers from different vendors
- statically linking the runtime library

Just to name a few.  Free every object from the same module that allocated it (often by exporting a deletion function, such as `IUnknown::Release()`).